# PhpStorm/Xdebug not stop in breakpoints

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug, breakpoints

I have problem to make xdebug working with PhpStorm, from log it's looks like that xdebug working fine, but PhpStorm from some reason not oblivious from it.
Also, the debugger working if I check "Break at first line in PHP scripts" from PHP->Debug setting menu, but than if I click "Resume program[F9]) it's skip my breakpoint, the telephone icon ("listen for PHP Debug connections")

I think I configure everything right and also pass the validation check:

[image]

my 20-xdebug.ini:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.var_display_max_data = -1
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = -1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.remote_mode="jit"
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="root project/laravel-storage/logs/xdebug-profiler.log"
xdebug.remote_log="root project/laravel-storage/logs/xdebug.log"
```

Here is my configuration:

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is log of one request:

```
Log opened at 2017-10-19 17:24:49
I: Connecting to configured address/port: localhost:9000.
I: Connected to client. :-)
-> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///home/michael/Pß3V" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="5.6.31-1~ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1" protocol_version="1.0" appid="15877"><engine version="2.5.5"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[http://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2017 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

<- feature_set -i 1 -n show_hidden -v 1
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="1" feature="show_hidden" success="1"></response>

<- feature_set -i 2 -n max_depth -v 1
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="2" feature="max_depth" success="1"></response>

<- feature_set -i 3 -n max_children -v 100
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="3" feature="max_children" success="1"></response>

<- status -i 4
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="status" transaction_id="4" status="starting" reason="ok"></response>

<- step_into -i 5
Log opened at 2017-10-19 17:24:49
I: Connecting to configured address/port: localhost:9000.
I: Connected to client. :-)
-> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///my project root/server.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="5.6.31-1~ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1" protocol_version="1.0" appid="15877" idekey="michael"><engine version="2.5.5"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[http://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2017 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

<- feature_set -i 1 -n show_hidden -v 1
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="1" feature="show_hidden" success="1"></response>

<- feature_set -i 2 -n max_depth -v 1
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="2" feature="max_depth" success="1"></response>

<- feature_set -i 3 -n max_children -v 100
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="3" feature="max_children" success="1"></response>

<- status -i 4
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="status" transaction_id="4" status="starting" reason="ok"></response>

<- step_into -i 5
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="step_into" transaction_id="5" status="break" reason="ok"><xdebug:message filename="file:///my project root/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php" lineno="749"></xdebug:message></response>

<- eval -i 6 -- aXNzZXQoJF9TRVJWRVJbJ1BIUF9JREVfQ09ORklHJ10p
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="6"><property type="bool"><![CDATA[0]]></property></response>

<- eval -i 7 -- aXNzZXQoJF9TRVJWRVJbJ1NFUlZFUl9OQU1FJ10p
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="7"><property type="bool"><![CDATA[1]]></property></response>

<- eval -i 8 -- KHN0cmluZykoJF9TRVJWRVJbJ1NFUlZFUl9OQU1FJ10p
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="8"><property type="string" size="9" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[bG9jYWxob3N0]]></property></response>

<- eval -i 9 -- KHN0cmluZykoJF9TRVJWRVJbJ1NFUlZFUl9QT1JUJ10p
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="9"><property type="string" size="4" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[ODAwMA==]]></property></response>

<- eval -i 10 -- KHN0cmluZykoJF9TRVJWRVJbJ1JFUVVFU1RfVVJJJ10p
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="10"><property type="string" size="15" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[L2FwaS92YXMtZW5hYmxl]]></property></response>

<- breakpoint_set -i 11 -t line -f file:///my project root/app/controllers/api/APIController_vas.php -n 45
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="11" id="158770017"></response>

<- stack_get -i 12
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stack_get" transaction_id="12"><stack where="Illuminate\Foundation\Application-&gt;handle" level="0" type="file" filename="file:///my project root/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php" lineno="749"></stack><stack where="Asm89\Stack\Cors-&gt;handle" level="1" type="file" filename="file:///my project root/vendor/asm89/stack-cors/src/Asm89/Stack/Cors.php" lineno="51"></stack><stack where="Illuminate\Session\Middleware-&gt;handle" level="2" type="file" filename="file:///my project root/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware.php" lineno="72"></stack><stack where="Illuminate\Cookie\Queue-&gt;handle" level="3" type="file" filename="file:///my project root/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Queue.php" lineno="47"></stack><stack where="Illuminate\Cookie\Guard-&gt;handle" level="4" type="file" filename="file:///my project root/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Guard.php" lineno="51"></stack><stack where="Stack\StackedHttpKernel-&gt;handle" level="5" type="file" filename="file:///my project root/vendor/stack/builder/src/Stack/StackedHttpKernel.php" lineno="23"></stack><stack where="Illuminate\Foundation\Application-&gt;run" level="6" type="file" filename="file:///my project root/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php" lineno="641"></stack><stack where="require_once" level="7" type="file" filename="file:///my project root/public/index.php" lineno="48"></stack><stack where="{main}" level="8" type="file" filename="file:///my project root/server.php" lineno="19"></stack></response>

<- run -i 13
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="run" transaction_id="13" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

<- run -i 14
Log closed at 2017-10-19 17:24:49
```

Comment: Change `xdebug.remote_mode` to a more standard one. `jit` is more for "break at exception" cases.

Comment: @LazyOne thanks, I tried both modes, non of them works for me :(

Comment: at which line did you set the breakpoint ? from my experience some breakpoints are ignored if they are set in the creation of associative arrays. Also it might be  worth to add xdebug_break() instead of setting breakpoints and see what happens

Comment: @AdrianBsc thanks, this is also not working for me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I though cookie needed only if wanted to debug via browser (I need only API calls), add cookie solved it:

```
XDEBUG_SESSION=PHPSTORM; path=/; domain=localhost; Expires=Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 GMT;
```