# PhpStorm debug mode is not working

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, phpstorm, xdebug

I installed PhpStorm and at the moment trying to configure the debug mode for my Symfony projects. If I use the Symfony functional test case unit and trying to debug in PHPUnit it gives the following error message if I import the `WebTestCase`:

> Unable to guess the Kernel directory.
>   vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Test/KernelTestCase.php:58
>   vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Test/KernelTestCase.php:128
>   vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Test/KernelTestCase.php:157
>   /vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Test/WebTestCase.php:33
>   tests/AppBundle/Controller/BlogControllerTest.php:20

The command which is running:

```
/usr/bin/php -dxdebug.remote_enable=1 -dxdebug.remote_mode=req
-dxdebug.remote_port=9000 -dxdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1 vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --no-configuration Tests\AppBundle\Controller\BlogControllerTest /Users/ahmetbas/PhpstormProjects/SymfonySwagger/tests/AppBundle/Controller/BlogControllerTest.php
--teamcity Testing started at 09:00 ... PHPUnit 6.4.3 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
```

**phpunit.xml.dist**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html -->
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/4.8/phpunit.xsd"
         backupGlobals="false"
         colors="true"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php">
    <php>
        <server name="KERNEL_DIR" value="app/" />
    </php>

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
            <directory>tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory>src</directory>
            <exclude>
                <directory>src/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                <directory>src/*/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                <directory>src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>
```

**php.ini**

```
...
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.8/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="/Applications/MAMP/tmp/xdebug"
```

**BlogControllerTest.php**

```
<?php

namespace Tests\AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class BlogControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{

    public function testListAction(){

        $client = static::createClient();
        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/blog/1');

        $this->assertGreaterThan(
            0,
            $crawler->filter('html:contains("test")')->count()
        );
    }

}
```

**AppKernel.php**

In my AppKernel `new Symfony\Bundle\WebServerBundle\WebServerBundle()` is enabled to use the client controller to check API route.

If I run the PHPUnit on my console outside of the PhpStorm IDE it's working without errors. What goes wrong?

Comment: I had some examples for correct configurations in my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46835798/phpstorm-xdebug-not-stop-in-breakpoints is it helps you? if you running it without xdebug it's works?

Comment: I hope these instructions help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45019201/phpstorm-debug-with-laravel-homestead-not-working/45019239#45019239

I have added all steps needed to get it working: server, browser and IDE settings

Comment: You may need to replace `<server name="KERNEL_DIR" value="app/" />` with `<server name="KERNEL_CLASS" value="\YourFullyQualifiedAppKernelClassName" />`